VideoPlayer Android12 not working but iOS does work
I am uploading videos to firebase storage with a method that handles both images and videos. The list of assets are given from PhotoManager; List<AssetEntity> and are converted into bytes to be stored in Firebase Realtime Database. The package works wonders for getting thumbnail data for videos on-device. After being uploaded, I use VideoPlayer to play the videos. Everything works wonders on iOS but I can't get it to work on Android 12+. Here is my uploadAssets method:
Future<String?> uploadMedia({
  required List<AssetEntity> assets,
  required String profileId,
  required String albumId,
}) async {
  await firebaseErrorHandler(() async {
    // Reference mediaPath = s.ref("$profileId/Albums/$albumId/Media/");
    Reference imagesPath = s.ref("$albumId/Images");
    Reference videoPath = s.ref("$albumId/Videos");
    Reference thumbnailPath = s.ref("$albumId/Thumbnails");

    // Firebase {album} reference by id
    CollectionReference docRef = mediaCollection(albumId);

    List<Future<String>> futures = assets.map((item) async {
      final bool isVideo = item.type == AssetType.video;
      final Uint8List? bytes = await item.originBytes;

      late Reference mediaRef;

      switch (item.type) {
        case AssetType.image:
          mediaRef = imagesPath.child(
            '${item.createDateTime.toIso8601String()}.jpg',
          );
          break;
        case AssetType.video:
          mediaRef = videoPath.child(
            '${item.createDateTime.toIso8601String()}.mp4',
          );
          break;
        default:
          throw Exception("Unsupported asset type.");
      }

      // specifying contentType so firestore knows file type & assigning downloadUrl.
      late String downloadUrl;
      if (bytes != null) {
        UploadTask task = mediaRef.putData(
          bytes,
          SettableMetadata(
            contentType: isVideo ? 'video/mp4' : 'image/jpeg',
          ),
        );
        TaskSnapshot snap = await task;
        downloadUrl = await snap.ref.getDownloadURL();
      } else {
        throw Exception("${item.id} is invalid.");
      }

      final Uint8List? thumbnailBytes = await item.thumbnailData;
      Reference thumbnailRef = thumbnailPath.child(
        item.createDateTime.toIso8601String(),
      );

      // Thumbnail & thumbnailDownloadUrl (optional)
      String thumbnailUrl = '';
      if (isVideo) {
        if (thumbnailBytes != null) {
          UploadTask thumbTask = thumbnailRef.putData(
            thumbnailBytes,
            SettableMetadata(contentType: 'image/jpeg'),
          );
          TaskSnapshot thumbSnap = await thumbTask;
          thumbnailUrl = await thumbSnap.ref.getDownloadURL();
        } else {
          UploadTask thumbTask = thumbnailRef.putData(
            customThumbnail,
            SettableMetadata(contentType: 'image/jpeg'),
          );
          TaskSnapshot thumbSnap = await thumbTask;
          thumbnailUrl = await thumbSnap.ref.getDownloadURL();
        }
      }

      late GeoPoint? geoPoint;
      if (item.latitude != null || item.longitude != null) {
        geoPoint = GeoPoint(item.latitude!, item.longitude!);
      }

      // adding Media object to firebase in Albums/{albumId}/Media
      await docRef.add(Media(
        docId: docRef.id,
        parentAlbumId: albumId,
        downloadUrl: downloadUrl,
        profileId: profileId,
        dateTime: DateTime.now(),
        mediaType: isVideo ? 'video' : 'image',
        exifDateTime: item.createDateTime,
        exifLocation: geoPoint,
        thumbnailUrl: thumbnailUrl,
        // duration: isVideo ? duration : null,
      ).toMap());

      return isVideo ? thumbnailUrl : downloadUrl;
    }).toList();

    // Extra
    List<String> uploadedUrls = await Future.wait(futures);

    if (uploadedUrls.isNotEmpty) {
      await albumCollection().doc(albumId).update({
        'thumbnail': uploadedUrls.last,
        'dateUpdated': DateTime.now(),
      });
    }
  }).then((err) {
    debugPrint(err);
    if (err != null) return err;
  });

For iOS, everything works great and videos are loaded successfully. Here are my AndroidManifest.xml permission definitions:
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

And here is an example downloadUrl:
gs://[...]/2024-04-04 10:10:40.000.mp4

Why are there spaces allowed in the file name?  Due to the nature of the web, files should not have a space and should convert spaces into a dash or underline.  This isn't an android problem as much as its a web file format naming based issue.

fixed file name to remove spaces, but the android simulator still wont work with the video file. My file name is {uuid}.mp4 with content type video/mp4 and ive specified permissions with androidmanifext.xml but its still having issues with the download url :/
